# Sending emails from the USA

Tags: email, delphi, ssl, indy

My program uses Indy 10 TIdSMTP and TIdMessage to send error reports via email. The program is used mainly in Germany, but some clients are in the USA.

The tool works flawlessly in Germany, but the USA clients are not able to send anything at all. The output shows that the connection to the German email server (smtp.web.de) is made, but after that, an immediate disconnect follows. The exception "Socket error #10054 connection reset by peer" is thrown.

Here's some code:

```
procedure SendMail(const PI_sSenderAddress: string; const PI_arrReceiverAddresses, PI_arrCCAddresses, PI_arrBCCAddresses: array of string; const PI_sSubject, PI_sMailText: string; const PI_arrAttachments: array of string; const PI_sHost: string = ''; const PI_sUsername: string = ''; const PI_sPassword: string = ''; const PI_bUseTLS: boolean = False; const PI_nPort: integer = 25; const PI_nTimeoutSeconds: integer = 5 );
var
  smtp: TIdSMTP;
  Mail: TIdMessage;
  i: integer;
  arrAttachments: array of TIdAttachmentFile;
  io: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  io := nil;
  smtp := TIdSMTP.Create(Application);
  try
    smtp.Password := PI_sPassword;
    smtp.Username := PI_sUsername;
    smtp.Port := PI_nPort;
    smtp.Host := PI_sHost;
    if PI_bUseTLS then begin
      io := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Application);
      smtp.IOHandler := io;
    end;
    smtp.UseTLS := utUseRequireTLS;
    if PI_sUserName <> '' then begin
      smtp.AuthType := satDefault;
    end else begin
      smtp.AuthType := satNone;
    end;
    smtp.HeloName := Split(PI_sUsername, 1, '@');

    mail := TIdMessage.Create( Application );
    try
      mail.Clear;
      mail.From.Address := PI_sSenderAddress;
      mail.From.Text := PI_sSenderAddress;
      mail.Subject := PI_sSubject;
      mail.Recipients.EMailAddresses := ArrayToStr( PI_arrReceiverAddresses, ',' ); //!! only one
      mail.CCList.EMailAddresses := ArrayToStr( PI_arrCCAddresses, ',' );
      mail.BccList.EMailAddresses := ArrayToStr( PI_arrBCCAddresses, ',' );
      mail.ReceiptRecipient.Text := '';
      mail.Body.Add( PI_sMailText );
      mail.Date := now;

      if Length(PI_arrAttachments) > 0 then begin
        SetLength(arrAttachments, Length(PI_arrAttachments));
        for i := 0 to High(PI_arrAttachments) do begin
          arrAttachments[i] := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(mail.MessageParts, PI_arrAttachments[i]);
        end;
      end;

      try
        smtp.ConnectTimeout := PI_nTimeoutSeconds * 1000;
        smtp.Connect;
      if smtp.Connected then begin
        smtp.Send(mail);
      end;
    finally
      smtp.disconnect;
      if Length(arrAttachments) > 0 then begin
        for i := 0 to High(arrAttachments) do begin
          arrAttachments[i].Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    mail.Free;
  end;
finally
  smtp.free;
  if Assigned(io) then io.Free;
end;
end;
```

I call it like this:

```
SendMail(
  'myaccount@web.de',
  ['receiver@web.de'],
  [],
  [],
  'Subject',
  'Text',
  [],
  'smtp.web.de',
  'myaccount@web.de',
  'mypassword',
  True,
  587
);
```

Can someone help?

EDIT: I changed to a googlemail account, but getting the same error. Currently, i call it like this:

I call it like this:

```
SendMail(
  'myaccount@gmail.com',
  ['receiver@web.de'],
  [],
  [],
  'Subject',
  'Text',
  [],
  'smtp.gmail.com',
  'myaccount@gmail.com',
  'mypassword',
  True,
  587
);
```

Comment: Could it be that *web.de* doesn't accept connections from outside Germany? This doesn't look like a Delphi, SSL or Indy problem to me. And why don't you use the default SMTP server of the user (don't ask me how to find out, but it should be possible)?

Comment: Hm, have to investigate this, thanks for the hint. I don't want the user to setup the email settings, that's why the SMTP server isnt accessible for me.

Comment: On the client side, you should be using `utUseImplicitTLS` or `utUseExplicitTLS` (depending on  `Port`), instead of `utUseRequireTLS`. And you shouldn't be setting `UseTLS` at all if `PI_bUseTLS` is false. And you don't need to free the `TIdAttachmentFile` objects manually, `TIdMessage` owns them and will free them for you. And don't use `Application` as the owner of objects you are managing lifetimes for.

Comment: Many American service providers block direct SMTP, at least on consumer connections, to reduce spam.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis You're right about the blocking. I created a googlemail account for this and it works fine. Make your comment an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @Sliver: you found a solution, so you can write the answer.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis I was wrong - me idiot tested it in germany. I just got the response back from an american friend - its the same error with the new account. I expected using smtp.googlemail.com or smtp.gmail.com to work. But it doesn't. Any further ideas?

Comment: @alcalde What would be the alternative then?

Comment: @Sliver Normally the solution is to use the ISP's SMTP server or an email provider's such as GMail. You've said that isn't working however. Could this be a firewall problem on their end - a security program blocking outbound SMTP?

Comment: Have you been into your gmail settings and enabled the: enable less secure apps?

Comment: @alcalde I told my american tester to deactivate the security for the test, but it didnt help. Anyways, i now switched to using the googlemail SSL port and it finally works.

Comment: @Shambhala I did not, but it was already enabled